# PowerBI reports and dashboard on-premise hosting

Tags: powerbi

As per available documentation, power bi reports and dashboards will be published to microsoft cloud. Can we configure on-premise server to host power bi reports just like SSRS reports?

Comment: What part of  the answer in your exact previous question did you not understand? It's not yet available, said the Microsoft Product Manager.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Power BI Reports hosting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30210638/power-bi-reports-hosting)

Comment: @SandeepYadav: Please use SO responsibly, do not post duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet, it's something we're looking at. Please use support.powerbi.com to get notified when we have that capability.

HTH,
-Lukasz

http://dev.powerbi.com

http://blogs.msdn.com/powerbidev

Answer (score 0):

This feature was in the Idea site of Power BI and they have just rolled out a preview.

https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/7948020-powerbi-reports-and-dashboard-on-premise-hosting

You can access the preview in the form of a Azure VM here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2016/10/25/announcing-a-technical-preview-of-power-bi-reports-in-sql-server-reporting-services